# Fixed a bug that KAA-1594: error after attaching endpoint to user

Tags: kaa

[The bug](http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/KAA-1594) in kaa 0.10 have Influenced my application development. So I try to fix it.Then I Compared the code of the kaa 0.9 and kaa 0.10. I have found the differences in class EndpointServiceImpl of Kaa DAO interface modular:there are two methods of attachEndpointToUser in it

1,

```
public EndpointProfileDto attachEndpointToUser(String endpointUserId, String
          endpointAccessToken) throws KaaOptimisticLockingFailureException {
    LOG.info("Try to attach endpoint with access token {} to user with {}", endpointAccessToken,
            endpointUserId);
    validateString(endpointUserId, "Incorrect endpointUserId "
                                   + endpointUserId);
    EndpointUser endpointUser = endpointUserDao.findById(endpointUserId);
    LOG.trace("[{}] Found endpoint user with id {} ", endpointUserId, endpointUser);
    if (endpointUser
        != null) {
      EndpointProfile endpoint = endpointProfileDao.findByAccessToken(endpointAccessToken);
      LOG.trace("[{}] Found endpoint profile by with access token {} ", endpointAccessToken,
              endpoint);
      if (endpoint
          != null) {
        if (endpoint.getEndpointUserId()
            == null
            || endpointUserId.equals(endpoint.getEndpointUserId())) {
          LOG.debug("Attach endpoint profile with id {} to endpoint user with id {} ", endpoint
                  .getId(), endpointUser.getId());
          List<String> endpointIds = endpointUser.getEndpointIds(); 

          **/*if (endpointIds
                  != null
                  && endpointIds.contains(endpoint.getId())) {
                LOG.warn("Endpoint is already assigned to current user {}.", endpoint
                        .getEndpointUserId());
                return getDto(endpoint);
          }*/**

          if (endpointIds
              == null) {
            endpointIds = new ArrayList<>();
            endpointUser.setEndpointIds(endpointIds);
          }
          endpointIds.add(endpoint.getId());
          endpointUser = endpointUserDao.save(endpointUser);
          while (true) {
            try {
              endpoint.setEndpointUserId(endpointUser.getId());
              LOG.trace("Save endpoint user {} and endpoint profile {}", endpointUser, endpoint);
              endpoint = endpointProfileDao.save(endpoint);
              break;
            } catch (KaaOptimisticLockingFailureException ex) {
              LOG.warn("Optimistic lock detected in endpoint profile ", Arrays.toString(endpoint
                      .getEndpointKey()), ex);
              endpoint = endpointProfileDao.findByKeyHash(Sha1HashUtils.hashToBytes(endpoint
                      .getEndpointKey()));
            }
          }
          return getDto(endpoint);
        } else {
          LOG.warn("Endpoint is already assigned to different user {}. Unassign it first!.",
                  endpoint.getEndpointUserId());
          throw new DatabaseProcessingException("Endpoint is already assigned to different user.");
        }
      } else {
        LOG.warn("Endpoint with accessToken {} is not present in db.", endpointAccessToken);
        throw new DatabaseProcessingException("No endpoint found for specified accessToken.");
      }
    } else {
      LOG.warn("Endpoint user with id {} is not present in db.", endpointUserId);
      throw new DatabaseProcessingException("Endpoint user is not present in db.");
    }
  }
```

2,

```
public EndpointProfileDto attachEndpointToUser(String userExternalId, String tenantId,
                                                 EndpointProfileDto profile) {
    validateString(userExternalId, "Incorrect userExternalId "
                                   + userExternalId);
    EndpointUser endpointUser = endpointUserDao.findByExternalIdAndTenantId(userExternalId,
            tenantId);
    if (endpointUser
        == null) {
      LOG.info("Creating new endpoint user with external id: [{}] in context of [{}] tenant",
              userExternalId, tenantId);
      EndpointUserDto endpointUserDto = new EndpointUserDto();
      endpointUserDto.setTenantId(tenantId);
      endpointUserDto.setExternalId(userExternalId);
      endpointUserDto.setUsername(userExternalId);
      endpointUser = endpointUserDao.save(endpointUserDto);
    }
    List<String> endpointIds = endpointUser.getEndpointIds();
    if (endpointIds
        == null) {
      endpointIds = new ArrayList<>();
      endpointUser.setEndpointIds(endpointIds);
    } **/*else if (endpointIds
               != null
               && endpointIds.contains(profile.getId())) {
      LOG.warn("Endpoint is already assigned to current user {}.", profile.getEndpointUserId());
      return profile;
    }*/**
    endpointIds.add(profile.getId());
    endpointUser = endpointUserDao.save(endpointUser);
    profile.setEndpointUserId(endpointUser.getId());
    while (true) {
      try {
        LOG.trace("Save endpoint user {} and endpoint profile {}", endpointUser, profile);
        return saveEndpointProfile(profile);
      } catch (KaaOptimisticLockingFailureException ex) {
        LOG.warn("Optimistic lock detected in endpoint profile ", Arrays.toString(profile
                .getEndpointKey()), ex);
        profile = findEndpointProfileByKeyHash(profile.getEndpointKeyHash());
        profile.setEndpointUserId(endpointUser.getId());
      }
    }
  }
```

The code above is in kaa 0.10 .Compared with the Kaa 0.9, it Added a judgment condition that in Bold code above:(

> if(endpointIds!=null&&endpointIds.contains(endpoint.getId()))   )

and

> else if (endpointIds
>                      != null
>                      && endpointIds.contains(profile.getId())).

I have made a test that Commented the judgment condition codes. The result is OK. I want to know that the fix method is available .

Answer (score 0):

You can contribute to kaa.
Description on this procedure you can find [here.](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Customization-guide/How-to-contribute/)

In few words about it:

1. fork kaa repository [here.](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa)
2. crete new branch with the content of branch you want to fix(release-0.10)
3. commit (commit message must begin with "KAA-1594:") and push changes into your fork.
4. create a pull request on kaa page (compare original kaa branch release-0.10 and your new edited branch)
5. allow changes from owners
6. you are done!

UPD: would be great if you describe the problem and your solution in issue on github it will help us to make official fix faster.